# How do I find the Lists folder on our website?

Tags: list, 2007, folder, web

First off, I have almost no experience with Sharepoint and some limited experience with websites.

I do have programming experience in Python, as well as some VB.Net and C#.

We have a Sharepoint based app that we access through a website. The path to Lists is listed in the URL as the below sample shows:

- http://testsite.foo.org/Lists/Hotels/AllItems.aspx

I can get on the server and get to testsite.foo.org in `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories`. But there's no Lists folder, or Hotels folder, there.

My guess is that the URL is being generated dynamically by AllItems.aspx, but that file is supposed to be in the directory structure I'm looking for.

When I search for `AllItems.aspx`, I get multiple returns, but none in `Lists\Hotels` (or any of the various other `Lists\Foo` URLs).
We're using Sharepoint 2007. If this question belongs in another forum, please let me know.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: My ultimate goal is to find the correct URL for a number of lists in the Team Site, or All Site Content for that matter, that are throwing an error. Also, thanks for your suggested edits, but I didn't understand what the purpose of them was.

Answer (score 2):

They are all on virtual folders, that are really located in the database. You need to download and install SharePoint Designer, and then you can view, manage, and create any content you need. Seeing that you are a developer, this is really something you could use in your toolset. You can download the SharePoint Designer 2007 package [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21581).

Answer (score 0):

The View created needs to be modified and include

> **Type**

in the column name. Steps to be follwed: Go to AllItems.aspx page. On the ribbon ..click on Modify this View....Select Type under the listed column and select Ok. You should see the folder on Allitems.aspx page now. 
Hope I got your answer right.

Comment: I don't think this is a view. I go to the Team Site, or All Site Content, and in the Lists pane on the left there is a large number of lists others have created. Some x number of them throw an error when clicked on, that so far I'm attributing to a bad URL. I'm trying to find the correct one for them.

Comment: a view is inside a list.. go to the url u mentioned. http://testsite.foo.org/Lists/Hotels/AllItems.aspx.....after that follow the steps i gave above.